# How to format text in an html object?

Tags: html, css

I have a text file from another system that I cannot change. I'd like to improve its appearance (e.g change the font family and font size) in an iFrame or Object but cannot find a way to apply CSS to the text.

```
<object id="warningsObject" type="text/plain" data="http://192.168.0.123/local/warnings.txt" style="width:400px; height:250px;">
Not supported
</object>
```

I've tried all the approaches I can imagine might work (put style statement in the object, in a div around the object, applied a class, set up CSS for the body & html etc). I can't get any of those to work.

Would prefer a solution without JQuery if possible ;)

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should use js and get the childElements of the object and set wanted styles to them

Comment: I did try that too, but maybe didn't do it correctly. Will try it again. Thanks

Comment: This doesnt work...

<object id="myObject" data="snippet.html" class="niceTxt" width="500" height="200">
</object>

<script>
document.getElementById("myObject").childNodes[0].style.fontSize = "45px";
</script>

Comment: Maybe because you try to find the elements before the text file is completely loaded.